# ASP.Net Core 3.1 - File Upload With View Model gets always NULL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, viewmodel, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to upload file to the server with a view model.

My Model is like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace XmlSigner.Data.Models
{
    public class XmlFile : BaseModel
    {
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        [ConcurrencyCheck]  //2 file should not be same
        [Column("FileContent", TypeName = "text"), Required(ErrorMessage = "File Content should be given"), MinLength(5), Display(Name = "File Content", Prompt = "Please Give File Content")]
        public string FileLocationInServer { get; set; }

        [Column("PreviousFileId"), Display(Name = "Previous Signed/Unsigned File", Prompt = "Please select Previous File")]
        public long? PreviousFileId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PreviousFileId"), Display(Name = "Previous Signed/Unsigned File", Prompt = "Please Select Previous File")]
        public virtual XmlFile PreviousSignedFile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My View Model is like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using XmlSigner.Data.Models;

namespace XmlSigner.ViewModels
{
    public class XmlFileAddViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "File Content should be given"), MinLength(5), Display(Name = "File Content", Prompt = "Please Give File Content")]
        public FormFile XmlFile { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Previous Signed/Unsigned File", Prompt = "Please select Previous File")]
        public long? PreviousFileId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PreviousFileId"), Display(Name = "Previous Signed/Unsigned File", Prompt = "Please Select Previous File")]
        public virtual XmlFile PreviousSignedFile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And View Form is like this:

```
<form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="XmlFile" class="control-label"></label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="XmlFile">
        <span asp-validation-for="XmlFile" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="PreviousFileId" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="PreviousFileId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.PreviousFileId"></select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And the controller is like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(XmlFileAddViewModel xmlFileAddViewModel)
{
    .........................
    .........................
}
```

What I am finding is:

[image]

So, what I am getting is the uploaded file gets null.

Can anyone help me to find why I am getting uploaded file to null?

### Update:

If I use **IFormFile** then I am getting this error-

```
  System.InvalidCastException: The field of type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormFile must be a string, array or ICollection type.
        at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MinLengthAttribute.IsValid(Object value)
        at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.IsValid(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.GetValidationResult(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations.DataAnnotationsModelValidator.Validate(ModelValidationContext validationContext)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.ValidateNode()
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitComplexType(IValidationStrategy defaultStrategy)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.Visit(ModelMetadata metadata, String key, Object model)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitChildren(IValidationStrategy strategy)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitComplexType(IValidationStrategy defaultStrategy)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.Visit(ModelMetadata metadata, String key, Object model)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.Validate(ModelMetadata metadata, String key, Object model, Boolean alwaysValidateAtTopLevel)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ObjectModelValidator.Validate(ActionContext actionContext, ValidationStateDictionary validationState, String prefix, Object model, ModelMetadata metadata)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.EnforceBindRequiredAndValidate(ObjectModelValidator baseObjectValidator, ActionContext actionContext, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, ModelBindingContext modelBindingContext, ModelBindingResult modelBindingResult)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
              at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
              at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
              at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
              at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
              at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
              at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
              at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
              at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
              at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
              at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
              at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
              at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
              at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: You're trying to bind a file input element to an Entity Framework model. Your `XmlFile` class has nothing to do with an HTML form's `<input type="file" />`. Use `IFormFile` as suggested. Then read the error: you have an irrelevant validation attribute on your file property.

Comment: If I use IFormFile, then I am finding this error- `  System.InvalidCastException: The field of type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormFile must be a string, array or ICollection type.`

Comment: Yes, I can read what the error message states. Did you read my comment? Did you read the stack trace? That's because you have a `MinLengthAttribute` on that property. That doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CodeCaster said, `MinLengthAttribute` is used to specify the minimum length of array or string data allowed in a property.So you could not declare for `IFormFile`.

Change like below:

```
public class XmlFileAddViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "File Content should be given"),Display(Name = "File Content", Prompt = "Please Give File Content")]
    public IFormFile XmlFile { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Previous Signed/Unsigned File", Prompt = "Please select Previous File")]
    public long? PreviousFileId { get; set; }
}
```

Reference:[MinLengthAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.minlengthattribute?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `IFormFile` instead of `FormFile` as follows:

```
public class XmlFileAddViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "File Content should be given"), MinLength(5), Display(Name = "File Content", Prompt = "Please Give File Content")]
    public IFormFile XmlFile { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Previous Signed/Unsigned File", Prompt = "Please select Previous File")]
    public long? PreviousFileId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Previous Signed/Unsigned File", Prompt = "Please Select Previous File")]
    public IFormFile PreviousSignedFile { get; set; }
}
```